# Unable to USE tooltips when viewing svg code

Tags: javascript, css, svg, highcharts, tooltip

I've searched around for several days and have not been able to find a solution to this issue. I'm generating highcharts with not problem. Inaddition, I'm using the below simple function to get the svg code for each chart.

```
 function generateSVG (){

     var svg_xml =  $('#container').highcharts().getSVG();

     document.getElementById('svg_code').innerHTML = svg_xml;
 }
```

My issue is that with the chart originally generated by highcharts I am able to mouseover the chart and see tooltips. However, when I later embed the generated svg code, even with including all the external resources, the tooltips do not work - everything becomes like a static image. After inspecting the svg code extracted next to the code used to generate the initial chart, I noticed that the line of code which includes the tooltip class for highcharts was missing in the extracted code. Am I missing something here.  Below is an example of one of the functions used to generate a chart.

```
function highArea(theD){

    setHighSize();

    var theData = theD;

    $.get(theData, function(data) {

        Highcharts.chart('chartDisplay', {
            colors: ["#67001f","#b2182b","#d6604d","#f4a582","#fddbc7","#ffffff"],
            chart: {
                type: "area",
                useHTML: true
            },
            exporting: {
                buttons: {
                    contextButton: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: chart_title
            },
            data: {
                csv: data
            },
            title: {
                text: chart_title
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value; 
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: some_label
                },
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name} <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/> {point.x}'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 2,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        generateSVG();

    });

}
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?  I would really appreciate any feedback on this matter.
Thanks :)

Comment: Showing a tooltip is done with browser events and javascript. When you generate svg image, you loose all js code - so the chart becomes a static image and it is not possible that the generated image will respond to mouse events.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Note that I didn't generate an svg image. I'm actually using the code extracted via the getSVG method call.

Comment: Still, it will be just a static picture - http://jsfiddle.net/23ey3tn0/3/